# OpenRecordset from Access using SQL back end -- "Invalid Argument" Error

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have been in the process of converting our access database to SQL and having problems with my OpenRecordset statement on line 2 .. 
(This code I have used for other SQL systems.. just not working now) Frustrating
Thanks for any help :) .. the SQL has a primary key and Identity field. thanks!
Joe

```
strsql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_login"
Set addrec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strsql, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
addrec.addNew
addrec.loginname = "Joe2"
addrec.Update
addrec.Close
```

Comment: What problems are you having with line 2?

Comment: "Not working"...what does that mean? Do you get an error message? Is the error message in the title of your question? Wouldn't it be simpler to use an insert statement?

Comment: If you manually open `tbl_login` in Datasheet View from the Navigation pane, can you add a new row there?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this the hard way.  You just need this:

```
strsql = "INSERT INTO tbl_login (loginname) VALUES ('joe2')"
CurrentDB.Execute strsql, dbFailOnError
```

Using the Execute method has some additional benefits; for one, you don't need to specify SetWarnings.  Additionally, you can trap errors and retain additional information.  For example, you could do something like this:

```
strsql = "INSERT INTO tbl_login (loginname) VALUES ('joe2')"
CurrentDB.Execute strsql, dbFailOnError
Debug.Print CurrentDB.RecordsAffected & " records were added"
```

Comment: When you want `RecordsAffected`, you have use an object variable set to `CurrentDb` instead of `CurrentDb` directly.  `CurrentDB.RecordsAffected` always gives you zero.

Comment: If the original code fails, so will yours, of course, using the same values. The issue is elsewhere.